# Windows desktop application that drastically decreases volume of loud sounds?

Tags: windows, audio

And do it temporarily so perhaps a button you press that turns on this loud sound muffling and then later you can turn audio back to regular. Example: if you were watching a boxing match, the program would ideally muffle the loud punching or loud cheering sounds.

Or if you suddenly got a popup that has loud music in it, the desktop program would hopefully muffle the loudness.

I use a windows 10 laptop.